# How can I run a certain function for a specific time in Python?

Tags: python, real-time

For example i have function do_something() and I want it to run for exactly 1 second (and not .923 seconds. It won't do. However 0.999 is acceptable.)

However it is very very important that the `do_something` must exactly run for 1 second. I was thinking of using UNIX time stamp and calculate the seconds. But I am really wondering if Python has a way to do this in a more aesthetic way...

The function `do_something()` is long-running, and must be interrupted after exactly one second.

Comment: Will it take less than one second, always, and you need to pad it? Will it ever take more than one second, and you want to reduce it?

Comment: Please clarify your question. Do you want to (a) run `do_something` once for exactly 1 second and then interrupt it, or (b) do you want to run `do_something` repeatedly until 1 second has passed, or (c) do you want to run `do_something` repeatedly until 1 second has passed *and* interrupt the most recent execution when 1 second passes?

Comment: no the do_something() function just does something... However it must only do what ever it is doing for only one second. It must cut off what it is doing if it is 1 second.

Comment: @JohnRoach: so option (a), then?

Comment: @JohnRoach: I've removed the `while` loop from your question because I think it made people think you were after option (b) or (c).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This bit of code might work for you. The description sounds like what you want:

http://programming-guides.com/python/timeout-a-function

It relies on the python `signal` module:

http://docs.python.org/library/signal.html

Comment: Actually, the `signals` module is not unix-only, but the `SIGALRM` signal is. However if you _are_ on unix, this would be a perfect solution. Especially if you don't have control over the contents of `do_something` .

Comment: unfortunately, the link to the website is broken by now - has been caught by a domain hostage service :(

Answer (score 2):

I gather from comments that there's a `while` loop in here somewhere. Here's a class that subclasses `Thread`, based on the source code for `_Timer` in the `threading` module. I know you said you decided against threading, but this is just a timer control thread; `do_something` executes in the main thread. So this should be clean. (Someone correct me if I'm wrong!):

```
from threading import Thread, Event

class BoolTimer(Thread):
    """A boolean value that toggles after a specified number of seconds:

    bt = BoolTimer(30.0, False)
    bt.start()
    bt.cancel() # prevent the booltimer from toggling if it is still waiting
    """

    def __init__(self, interval, initial_state=True):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.interval = interval
        self.state = initial_state
        self.finished = Event()

    def __nonzero__(self):
        return bool(self.state)

    def cancel(self):
        """Stop BoolTimer if it hasn't toggled yet"""
        self.finished.set()

    def run(self):
        self.finished.wait(self.interval)
        if not self.finished.is_set():
            self.state = not self.state
        self.finished.set()
```

You could use it like this.

```
import time

def do_something():
    running = BoolTimer(1.0)
    running.start()
    while running:
        print "running"              # Do something more useful here.
        time.sleep(0.05)             # Do it more or less often.
        if not running:              # If you want to interrupt the loop, 
            print "broke!"           # add breakpoints.
            break                    # You could even put this in a
        time.sleep(0.05)             # try, finally block.

do_something()
```

Answer (score 1):

The 'sched' module of Python appears suitable:

http://docs.python.org/library/sched.html

Apart from that: Python is not a real-time language nor does it usually run on a real-time OS. So your requirement is kind of questionable.

Comment: "Python is not a real-time language" I know I know... I hat it when a language is forced fed to me. It really wasn't my choice. I will check sched. It looks promising.

Comment: So you are saying basically I should simply schedule my function for each step?